# How to check if email address is a recipient and, if not, add email address as a CC?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to program Outlook VBA to:

1. automatically bcc one email, and
2. check if a second email address is a recipient (including cc and bcc) and if it is, don't do anything but if it is not, then add the second email as a cc.

The code below adds the second email address as a cc even if it already is a cc causing the second email address to be listed twice in the cc line. How can I fix this code? Below is the code. Thank you!

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, _
                                 Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim objRecip As Recipient
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim res As Integer
    Dim strBcc As String
    Dim strcc As String
    Dim pkemailcounter As Integer
    On Error Resume Next

    pkemailcounter = 0

    ' #### USER OPTIONS ####
    ' address for Bcc -- must be SMTP address
    ' or resolvable to a name in the address book
    strBcc = "email1@exampleemail.com"
    
    Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc)
    objRecip.Type = olBCC
     If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
        strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
                 "Do you want to send the message?"
        res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
                "Could Not Resolve Bcc")
        If res = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If

    For Each Recipient In Item.Recipients
      If (Recipient.Address = "email2@exampleemail.com") Then
        pkemailcounter = pkemailcounter + 1
        Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    If pkemailcounter = 0 Then
    strcc = "email2@exampleemail.com"
    Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strcc)
    objRecip.Type = olCC
    If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
        strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
                 "Do you want to send the message?"
        res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
                "Could Not Resolve cc")
        If res = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
    End If

    Set objRecip = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you comment out the `On Error Resume Next` ?

Comment: The email will be sent without any error. I just sent an email and email2 was in the to: line and the code still added it to the cc line.

Answer (score 0):

If you re-structure your code to break it up a bit it might be easier to figure out where the problem lies:

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    ' #### USER OPTIONS ####
    ' address for Bcc -- must be SMTP address
    ' or resolvable to a name in the address book
    Const strBcc As String = "email1@exampleemail.com"
    Const strCc As String = "email2@exampleemail.com"

    Dim objRecip As Recipient

    If Not TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then Exit Sub 'only handle emails

    Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc)
    objRecip.Type = olBCC
    If Not CheckResolve(objRecip) Then Cancel = True

    If HasRecipient(Item, strCc) Then Exit Sub

    Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strCc)
    objRecip.Type = olCC
    If Not CheckResolve(objRecip) Then Cancel = True

End Sub

'does a mail  `itm` have `recip` as a recipient?
Function HasRecipient(itm As MailItem, recip As String) As Boolean
    Dim rcp As Recipient
    For Each rcp In itm.Recipients
        If UCase(recip) = UCase(rcp.Address) Then
            HasRecipient = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next rcp
End Function

'Return True if recipient can be resolved, or if it can't
'    but the user elects to send anyway
Function CheckResolve(objRecip As Recipient) As Boolean
    Dim rType As String, strMsg As String

    rType = IIf(objRecip.Type = olCC, "CC", "BCC")
    If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
        strMsg = "Could not resolve the " & rType & " recipient. " & _
                 "Do you still want to send the message?"
        CheckResolve = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
                               "Could Not Resolve " & rType) = vbYes
    Else
        CheckResolve = True
    End If
End Function
```